# Java select query throws an error on DB2 database?

Tags: java, db2

Java DB2 Sql command throws an error if i have a `'` in my String i tried to replace it with a escape sequence but it would not work on the DB2 end any help ? I want the `'` to be present in the String.

Error

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-10, SQLSTATE=42603, SQLERRMC=', DRIVER=3.63.123
```

Java

```
String FUNC_VP = "Chris O'Connor/Henry/George";
String myQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT(VICE_PRES) FROM EMP_HC WHERE FUNC_VP ='"+funcvp_name.replace("'", "/'")+"'";
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String FUNC_VP = "Chris O''Connor/Henry/George";
```

To escape an apostrohe on DB2 it seems you have to use two apostrophes

Comment: (Not downvoting because this _is_ technically correct, but...)  No, don't escape them yourself - this is just papering over a larger problem: the op may be (probably is) open to SQL Injection.  Use prepared statements (As the other answer states), and you don't even have to do the escaping yourself.  There should be no reason to ever need to do the escaping yourself for a statement.

Answer (score 8):

Use a `PreparedStatement` and its `setParameter()` methods. It will handle things like escaping for you, and you'll never have to wonder how a particular database might handle things. It also prevents SQL injection, so there's no good reason not to use it.